# HANA Query: CASE WHEN, without SELECT Statment

Tags: hana, sapb1

I want to understand the CASE WHEN Statment in SAP HANA Query.

It is now to write a Value in a Column, only if there is a Value in the Column before.
"$[$3.U_chsBestNr2.0]" is the Column before (i get the value of this Column with this Statement).

```
CASE WHEN $[$3.U_chsBestNr2.0] <> '' THEN
SELECT T1."Name"
FROM OPOR T0  
LEFT JOIN "@CHS_BEL_BELEGTYP" T1 ON T0."U_chsBelTyp" = T1."Code"
WHERE T0."DocEntry" = $[$3.U_chsBestNr2.0] AND T0."DocStatus" = 'O'
END CASE
```

The Error appear always as follow:

```
...257 sql error: incorrect syntax near "CASE"..
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  CASE is not an SQL statement, but you can use it within a statement.  It sounds like you should be performing an UPDATE, but I don't understand from your description what it is you are trying to do.